# Created Entity Model can not be generated in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I needed to change the model of my database and I have done that via Entity Model Diagram as shown below.

[image: Model Diagram]

Here is the City mapping

[image: City Mapping]

I have deleted an association between Medical (this holds Hospitals and Clinics) and City because this association was completely wrong, I had to connect actually MedicalService and City.

Then I have created a new entity called CityService. Since relation between MedicalService and City is many to many I have needed such a table.

After that point, I was thinking all I had to do was "Generate Database from Model" but first I got an error as "entity type is not mapped", I have overcome this issue somehow (still I don't know how, it has been resolved somehow) then I have clicked again "Generate Database from Model" and it first deleted and droped everything and then created again.

But on my database there isn't generated any table called CityService. Should I created it manually or did I do something wrong? Or at least, tell me your opinion if it normally has to work or not? I am pretty new to EF.

I have manually created a table called CityService with the exact properties on the physical database. Then just for test purpose, I have added test1 scalar property to the CityService Entity and test2 scalar property to the City Entity, this time when I choosed "Generate Database from Model", it has done some changes to the web.config, I have saved and run the page and I got the following error:

[image: error]

and Inner Exception

[image]

Comment: Can you show your edmx?

Comment: @Pawel Sorry I can not get that, is the model diagram not displayed on the question as image?

Comment: from your description it seems to me that the mapping is broken (e.g. CityService entity is mapped to a table not called CityService). Mapping and store model is not shown on the screenshot (probably it would not be even possible). Since you don't know how the original issue with mapping was resolved it is impossible to tell how your model is mapped to the database just from your screenshot.

Comment: @Pawel thanks for your patient, I have inserted new images. I hope, those are the ones you were asking for if not please let me know.

Comment: in the mapping it says the the CityService entity is mapped to the City table - so here is your missing table.

Comment: @Pawel I don't understand that, according to my logic, it says CityService Entity is mapped to CityService and City entity is mapped to City table. On the first image, CityService is selected so it shows the mapping of the CityService. At the second image, it shows the mapping of City Entity. Or am I missing something? By the way I have updated the question, its getting more weird. Ok I can delete the whole entity and create it again I know but I don't want to do that, If I change something on the entity, I want to update my db accordingly or vice versa. By the way Visual Studio 2010 EF 4.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39219/discussion-between-mctuna-and-pawel)

Comment: show the edmx. the screenshots are not enough to grasp the full picture (pun intended :) )

Comment: = ) I guess, I have to read much much more about EF, I am even unable to ask my question properly

Comment: To get the .edmx XML, right-click it in the Solution Explorer, select `Open With`, and select `XML Editor`.  You should be able to copy and paste it at that point.

Comment: @mctuna - For the last screenshot - you need to regenerate (or remove) views. Since the model changed the pre-generated views you had no longer match. You can remove them (and they will be generated at runtime) or update them so that they match.